# IAsyncResult reference

Tags: c#

Why does `IAsyncResult` require I keep a reference to the Delegate that `BeginInvoked` it?

I would like to be able to write something like:

```
new GenericDelegate(DoSomething).BeginInvoke(DoSomethingComplete);

void DoSomethingComplete(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    ar.EndInvoke();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to keep your own reference to a delegate when doing a normal<sup>1</sup> delegate `BeginInvoke`; you can cast the `IAsyncResult` to an `AsyncResult` and retrieve the delegate from the `AsyncDelegate` property. And before anybody says "that's a dirty hack", [it's documented as being valid at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.messaging.asyncresult.aspx).

> The AsyncResult class is used in conjunction with asynchronous method calls made using delegates. The IAsyncResult returned from the delegate's BeginInvoke method can be cast to an AsyncResult. The AsyncResult has the AsyncDelegate property that holds the delegate object on which the asynchronous call was invoked.

So you could write:

```
new GenericDelegate(DoSomething).BeginInvoke(DoSomethingComplete);

void DoSomethingComplete(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    ((GenericDelegate)((AsyncResult)ar).AsyncDelegate)).EndInvoke();
}
```

Note that you do still have to know the *type* of the original delegate (or at least, I haven't found a way around this limitation; then again I haven't tried).

---

<sup>1</sup> By "normal" here I mean a `BeginInvoke` on a delegate instance, using the compiler-generated method. This technique of casting to `AsyncResult` is not guaranteed to work when using pre-defined methods, i.e. when using a class which declares its own `BeginX/EndX` methods. This is because the class may be doing something more clever internally such as blocking on IO completion ports, and may therefore use a different type of `IAsyncResult`. However, in the scenario as posited, it will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I find the whole Begin/End pattern unnecessarily complex - so I [had a look at wrapping it up](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/02/async-without-pain.html) (very comparable to what F# uses). Result: no more need to keep the delegate (etc).

Comment: +1 - I'm not sure it simplifies working with normal delegates that much (see my answer for why) but I like that it works with pre-defined BeginX/EndX methods as well. Closures FTW!

Answer (score 1):

IAsyncResult is a very ... overused interface.  To be a usable interface in so many scenarios it can only really have the properties and fields which are applicable to all scenarios in which it is used.  Otherwise APIs would be struggling to provide parameters which were simply not natural to their specific needs.

In only a subset of the circumstances is the creation of a IAsyncResult occur for a delegate.  Other scenarios like Control.BeginInvoke do not begin with a delegate and would not be able to supply one to the interface properties if they existed.

IAsyncResult takes the minimalist approach here and has only the properties all uses of it can supply.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the delegate as the async state parameter such as,

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Action d = delegate {
            Console.WriteLine("From the delegate");
        };
        var e = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        d.BeginInvoke(r => {
            ((Action)r.AsyncState).EndInvoke(r);
            e.Set();
        }, d);
        e.WaitOne();
    }
}
```

Comment: Simpler to capture "d": d.BeginInvoke(r => {d.EndInvoke(r); ...}, null); [as per the blog post linked above].